# Getting different time performace when running the same CUDA code for multiple times?

Tags: performance, cuda

I want to see the performance gain of using kernel fusion by running this code. But I got different run time for the same piece of code.

```
template <class T>
struct square
{
    __host__ __device__
    T operator()(const T &x) const
    {
        return x * x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    const int numOfEle = 500;
    std::cout<<"profiling norm with " << numOfEle << " elements" << std::endl;
    thrust::device_vector<float> dv(numOfEle);
    thrust::sequence(dv.begin(), dv.end());
    float init = 0.0f;
    float norm = 0.0f;
    float miliseconds = 0.0f;

    // same code runs for multiple times
    cudaEventRecord(start);
    norm = thrust::transform_reduce(dv.begin(), dv.end(), square<float>(), init, thrust::plus<float>());
    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&miliseconds, start, stop);
    std::cout<<"transform_reduce: "<<"norm:"<<norm<<",miliseconds:"<<miliseconds<<std::endl;

    // same code runs for multiple times
    cudaEventRecord(start);
    norm = thrust::transform_reduce(dv.begin(), dv.end(), square<float>(), init, thrust::plus<float>());
    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&miliseconds, start, stop);
    std::cout<<"transform_reduce: "<<"norm:"<<norm<<",miliseconds:"<<miliseconds<<std::endl;

    // same code runs for multiple times
    cudaEventRecord(start);
    norm = thrust::transform_reduce(dv.begin(), dv.end(), square<float>(), init, thrust::plus<float>());
    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&miliseconds, start, stop);
    std::cout<<"transform_reduce: "<<"norm:"<<norm<<",miliseconds:"<<miliseconds<<std::endl;

    cudaEventRecord(start);
    thrust::device_vector<float> dv2(numOfEle);
    thrust::transform(dv.begin(), dv.end(), dv2.begin(), square<float>());
    norm = thrust::reduce(dv2.begin(), dv2.end(), 0.0f, thrust::plus<float>());
    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&miliseconds, start, stop);
    std::cout<<"naive implementation: norm:"<<norm<<",miliseconds:"<<miliseconds<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result I got.

```
profiling norm with 500 elements
transform_reduce: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.323232
transform_reduce: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.192128
transform_reduce: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.186848
naive implementation: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.211328
```

Why is the first run time(0.323232) so large? Is there anything I missed here to profile a CUDA program? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first execution time is the slowest because it incurs some additional runtime API setup latency compared with the other calls. But your example is really only measuring latency rather than computation time anyway, because the parallel work in your example is so small. Consider the following modification of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <cuda_profiler_api.h>
template <class T>
struct square
{
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(const T &x) const { return x * x; }
};

void dorun(int numOfEle, int Nreps)
{
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    std::cout<<"profiling norm with " << numOfEle << " elements" << std::endl;
    thrust::device_vector<float> dv(numOfEle);
    thrust::sequence(dv.begin(), dv.end());
    thrust::device_vector<float> dv2(numOfEle);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaProfilerStart();
    for(int i=0; i<Nreps; i++) {
        float norm = 0.0f, miliseconds = 0.0f;
        cudaEventRecord(start);
        thrust::transform(dv.begin(), dv.end(), dv2.begin(), square<float>());
        norm = thrust::reduce(dv2.begin(), dv2.end(), 0.0f, thrust::plus<float>());
        cudaEventRecord(stop);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&miliseconds, start, stop);
        std::cout<<i<<" naive implementation: norm:"<<norm<<",miliseconds:"<<miliseconds<<std::endl;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<Nreps; i++) {
        float init = 0.0f, norm = 0.0f, miliseconds = 0.0f;
        cudaEventRecord(start);
        norm = thrust::transform_reduce(dv.begin(), dv.end(), square<float>(), init, thrust::plus<float>());
        cudaEventRecord(stop);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&miliseconds, start, stop);
        std::cout<<i<<" transform_reduce: norm:"<<norm<<",miliseconds:"<<miliseconds<<std::endl;
    }
    cudaProfilerStop();
}

int main()
{
    const int Nreps = 4;
    int numOfEle = 500;

    for(int i=0; i<7; i++, numOfEle *= 10) {
        dorun(numOfEle, Nreps);
        cudaDeviceReset();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here the two versions of transformed reduction are run several times each, at several different sizes, with the naïve version first, just to confirm that this isn't a property of `transform_reduce`:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 runtime.cu -o runtime
$ ./runtime
profiling norm with 500 elements
0 naive implementation: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.345088
1 naive implementation: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.219968
2 naive implementation: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.215008
3 naive implementation: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.212864
0 transform_reduce: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.196704
1 transform_reduce: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.194432
2 transform_reduce: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.19328
3 transform_reduce: norm:4.15417e+07,miliseconds:0.192992
profiling norm with 5000 elements
0 naive implementation: norm:4.16542e+10,miliseconds:0.312928
1 naive implementation: norm:4.16542e+10,miliseconds:0.194784
2 naive implementation: norm:4.16542e+10,miliseconds:0.192032
3 naive implementation: norm:4.16542e+10,miliseconds:0.191008
0 transform_reduce: norm:4.16542e+10,miliseconds:0.179232
1 transform_reduce: norm:4.16542e+10,miliseconds:0.177568
2 transform_reduce: norm:4.16542e+10,miliseconds:0.177664
3 transform_reduce: norm:4.16542e+10,miliseconds:0.17664
profiling norm with 50000 elements
0 naive implementation: norm:4.16654e+13,miliseconds:0.288864
1 naive implementation: norm:4.16654e+13,miliseconds:0.189472
2 naive implementation: norm:4.16654e+13,miliseconds:0.186464
3 naive implementation: norm:4.16654e+13,miliseconds:0.18592
0 transform_reduce: norm:4.16654e+13,miliseconds:0.174848
1 transform_reduce: norm:4.16654e+13,miliseconds:0.190176
2 transform_reduce: norm:4.16654e+13,miliseconds:0.173216
3 transform_reduce: norm:4.16654e+13,miliseconds:0.187744
profiling norm with 500000 elements
0 naive implementation: norm:4.16665e+16,miliseconds:0.300192
1 naive implementation: norm:4.16665e+16,miliseconds:0.203936
2 naive implementation: norm:4.16665e+16,miliseconds:0.2008
3 naive implementation: norm:4.16665e+16,miliseconds:0.199232
0 transform_reduce: norm:4.16665e+16,miliseconds:0.197984
1 transform_reduce: norm:4.16665e+16,miliseconds:0.191776
2 transform_reduce: norm:4.16665e+16,miliseconds:0.192096
3 transform_reduce: norm:4.16665e+16,miliseconds:0.191264
profiling norm with 5000000 elements
0 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+19,miliseconds:0.525504
1 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+19,miliseconds:0.50608
2 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+19,miliseconds:0.505216
3 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+19,miliseconds:0.504896
0 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+19,miliseconds:0.345792
1 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+19,miliseconds:0.344736
2 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+19,miliseconds:0.344512
3 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+19,miliseconds:0.34384
profiling norm with 50000000 elements
0 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+22,miliseconds:4.56586
1 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+22,miliseconds:4.5408
2 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+22,miliseconds:4.62774
3 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+22,miliseconds:4.54912
0 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+22,miliseconds:1.68493
1 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+22,miliseconds:1.67744
2 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+22,miliseconds:1.76778
3 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+22,miliseconds:1.86694
profiling norm with 500000000 elements
0 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+25,miliseconds:63.7808
1 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+25,miliseconds:63.813
2 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+25,miliseconds:62.8569
3 naive implementation: norm:4.16667e+25,miliseconds:61.5553
0 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+25,miliseconds:14.7033
1 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+25,miliseconds:14.6545
2 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+25,miliseconds:14.655
3 transform_reduce: norm:4.16667e+25,miliseconds:14.5933
```

Note how the execution time actually doesn't change as the sample size increases until we reach 5000000 elements, and that at 500000000 elements, the first solution is no longer the slowest. This is all because of fixed latency, which becomes irrelevant once the actual parallel work is much larger than the fixed latency.

So let's look in detail at some profiler output. First some API traces for the first kernel launch in the transform call at a small size:

```
240.66ms  2.6860us  cudaFuncGetAttributes
240.66ms  2.5910us  cudaFuncGetAttributes
240.66ms     527ns  cudaConfigureCall
240.66ms     401ns  cudaSetupArgument
240.67ms  1.7100ms  cudaLaunch (void thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::launch_by_value<unsigned int=0, thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::cuda_task<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::parallel_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::concurrent_group<
```

and then for the second:

```
242.82ms  2.6440us  cudaFuncGetAttributes
242.83ms  2.6460us  cudaFuncGetAttributes
242.83ms     557ns  cudaConfigureCall
242.83ms     394ns  cudaSetupArgument
242.83ms  16.992us  cudaLaunch (void thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::launch_by_value<unsigned int=0, thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::cuda_task<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::parallel_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::concurrent_group<
```

The first asynchronous launch takes 1.7ms, whereas the second takes 16us. But if we look at the GPU trace for the same execution, we see this for the first call:

```
   Start  Duration            Grid Size      Block Size     Regs*    SSMem*    DSMem*      Size  Throughput           Device   Context    Stream  Name
229.58ms  2.0800us              (1 1 1)      (1024 1 1)        12       32B        0B         -           -  GeForce GTX 970         1         7  void thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::launch_by_value<unsigned int=0, thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::cuda_task<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::parallel_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::concurrent_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::agent<unsigned long=1>, unsigned long=0>, unsigned long=0>, thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::closure<thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_kernel, thrust::tuple<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::cursor<unsigned int=0>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::detail::wrapped_function<thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<square<float>>, void>, unsigned int, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>>>(unsigned long=1) [163]
```

and this for the second:

```
230.03ms  2.1120us              (1 1 1)      (1024 1 1)        12       32B        0B         -           -  GeForce GTX 970         1         7  void thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::launch_by_value<unsigned int=0, thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::cuda_task<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::parallel_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::concurrent_group<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::agent<unsigned long=1>, unsigned long=0>, unsigned long=0>, thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::closure<thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n_detail::for_each_kernel, thrust::tuple<thrust::system::cuda::detail::bulk_::detail::cursor<unsigned int=0>, thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<float>>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>, thrust::detail::wrapped_function<thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<square<float>>, void>, unsigned int, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>>>>(unsigned long=1) [196]
```

Both kernels take a little over 2us to run, i.e. much less time that it takes for an API call to launch them. So it is additional API latency which is the cause of the timing difference, not any change in the performance of the code itself.